# Knockout bind function in IF statement

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, binding

I need to get a value from the ViewModel using a value from an object located in a loop in the view/page.

```
 <!-- ko foreach: ExtendedItems() -->
 <tr>
     <!-- ko foreach: PriceGroups() -->
     <!-- ko if: DeductibleAmount() === $root.FindDeductibleValue($parent.Provider()) -->
     <td> --Content-- </td>
     <!-- /ko -->
     <!-- /ko -->
 </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

I have a function in the ViewModel that finds the correct value:

```
 self.FindDeductibleValue = function (provider) {                
     return self.SelectedDeductibles.findObs('Provider', { Provider: provider }).Value();            
 }
```

This function works fine when I call it from the ViewModel, but I get "Cannot read property 'Value' of null at viewModel.self.FindDeductibleValue" when I try to use it in the view/page in the IF statement.

I've replaced `$parent.Provider()` with a number just to make sure that `$parent.Provider()` is not null, but it doesn't change the error I receive.

Is it not possible to use a function in an IF statement this way?

Comment: Whoops! Actually, this works... I needed to fill `SelectedDeductibles` before I try to bind the data. Where I was trying the function in the ViewModel it was already filled, but it wasn't filled yet when I tried to bind it in the IF statement in the view/page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is "binding context". Couple things first though.

> **EDIT:**
>
> I just noticed that the method `FindDeductibleValue()` receives
>   something other than the currently iterated item, like knockout does
>   automatically. And the code within it seems a little strange. Can you
>   please post the full view models you're working with? I'm not
>   convinced there's enough context to answer the problem correctly here.

1. I would use the `$parents` array not `$root` in case the depth or pattern ever changes.
2. You don't need to invoke your observables in your bindings, knockout will do this for you. `<!-- ko foreach: ExtendedItems -->` instead of  `<!-- ko foreach: ExtendedItems() -->`.
3. The main error you're encountering is a binding context issue, whereby when invoking the method from within the loop, you are essentially within a child context of the viewmodel. Unfortunately, JavaScript isn't able to tell you this. But it is telling you the problem. The child item doesn't have a `Value` property. In order to fix this you need to bind to the correct context I believe the code would be: 
   `$parents[0].FindDeductibleValue.bind(null, $parent.Provider())`